# Preferences in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings, preferences

How can I use preferences in WP7 through code and what is the class?

Can I make something like in android with the preferences activity and the preferences manager? Is there anything similar to this in WP7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no centralized settings/preferences management in the Windows Phone 7 framework. For guidance on how to create a settings page within your application, take a look at [How to: Create a Settings Page for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN.